# Couldn't load xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I'm getting 
**Couldn't load CastNear.xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace**

error. I tried to restart Xcode and the whole Mac but i didn't help.

any clue please?

Comment: I had the same issue...got it solved by quitting Xcode completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine after some time. I closed all project in Xcode and restarted MAc.

but i'm not sure what was the real reason though. anyway, i works fine now.

Comment: a simple restart of Xcode was enough for me.